# How do I get a properly instantiated object using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

There is a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61843) that says that if you use `fetch_object('classname')` it will call the **_*set*** method before the **_construct**. So how do you get the object instantiated before it calls the **__set** method.

Comment: there is no way. all you can do is workaround this bug/functonality.

Comment: So do I just use the `mysqli_result` and manually populate a new object or is there a better way.

Comment: depends on the nature of your object. this bug only affect you, if you use some properties in your __set() method which are only initialized in your __construct method. if you manage to break this dependency, you might use fetch_object() again. for classes without __set() method the current implementation is convenient, because the data is alread set when processing the constructor.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I guess I have to get out of the .Net mentality where trying to set the properties before the constructor would result in a Null reference exception.

Comment: great, i've wrapped it up in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this Bug/Feature is an interesting PHP Flaw. It is handy in cases like this:

```
class MyModel {

    public $id;
    public $column2;
    public $column3;

    public function __construct() {
        //work with prefilled properties from database here
    }
}

$model = $mysqli->query()->fetch_object('MyModel');
```

and it even works in this case:

```
class MyModel {

    public $data;

    public function __construct() {
        //work with $this->data here
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }
}

$model = $mysqli->query()->fetch_object('MyModel');
```

but it bites you in cases like this:

```
class MyModel {

    public $data;

    public function __construct($someOtherService) {
        $this->service = $someOtherService;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->service->workWith($name, $value);
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }
}

$model = $mysqli->query()->fetch_object('MyModel');
```